# Preventing lazy evaluation in Neo4J / Scala

Tags: scala, neo4j

I've written a DAO that performs a traversal using GraphDatabaseService.traversalDescription(), and maps the results into a data structure of the form `Map[X, Map[Y, Seq[X]]`.

I'm getting a `NotInTransactionException` when trying to evaluate the data structure later on.

I've tried to use the toList method to force any ResourceIterators to eagerly evaluate. I now have problems with NodeProxy.

Any suggestions?

Comment: I can include a code sample if necessary. Just need to unravel my code into a canonical form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to materialise the Neo4J lazy data structures:

- Iterables / Seqs required a `.toList`
- Maps (at all depths) required a `.toList.toMap`